# Magento 2 place order error

Tags: magento2, product, quantity, place-order, googlepay

I am getting below error in place order with "google pay"

[2021-06-30 12:00:06] report.CRITICAL: Error message {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): The requested qty is not available at Magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php:1711)"} []

I have checked a product has a qty = 1, then also error appearing any thoughts ?
what can be the cause of the issue ?

The quoterepo is already instantiated above

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
```

& then it again uses "`quoteRepository`" to save quote `$this->quoteRepository->save($quote)`, it should used the same instance which loaded before.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: did you use MSI?

Comment: How can i check that ?

Comment: See product qty - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/10074245?key=318737950a8c9ab2e2c56dbe6e96ad77

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Not using MSI in website

Answer (score 0):

The quoterepo is already instantiated above in code
like

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
```

& then it again uses "`quoteRepository`" to save quote like `$this->quoteRepository->save($quote)`, it should used the same instance which loaded before.

Using `$quote->save();`

error gone.

Comment: any thoughts on this solution ?